# Building Backoffice without SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am in the process of migrating a project from **Symfony 2.8** to **3.4**.

In this project , I used **sonataUserBundle** as a dependency ( before migrating ) which unfortunately does not work in **Symfony 3**.

So, I tried to use **SonataAdminBundle**  with **FosUserBundle** and I removed the **SonataUserBundle** dependency.

After removing "sonata_user" configuration from **config.yml file**   , I had the following exception:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route" admin_del_user_user_edit "as such route does not exist.").

So my question is :  is it possible to remove **sonataUserBundle** and use only **sonataAdminBundle** and **FosUserBundle** in order to build a back office?

How can I resolve the routeNotFoundException ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, in fact you can find a whole sample in symfony website  in this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_sonata_admin_without_user_bundle.html)

Code used in the short guide can be found [here](https://github.com/kunicmarko20/guard-talk-example) with support for different Symfony versions.